# Expanding an inequality with an absolute value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a rather brief and newbie algebra question.

If I have something like $|q|$ $\lt r + |p|$

Is this expanded out as

$-r - |p| < q < r + |p|$

or

$-r + |p| < q < r + |p|$

I want to say it is the first, but I am a little bit confused. Is it the first one? If so, why? I am aware of the property $|a|$ $\le $b => -b $\lt$ a $\lt$ b but can b simply be "anything"?

Comment: What do you mean by expanded out? In the first instance, you have equality, and the next two instances are both inequalities.

Comment: Sorry -- there was a typo. It is |q| < r + |p|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your variables are real scalars, 
one can write down easily that
it's the first:
$-r - |p| < q < r + |p|$

you see this by inspecting the two cases:

$q > 0$, then $q = |q| < r + |p|$.

$q < 0$, then $- q = |q| < r + |p|$, i.e. $ q >  -(r + |p|)$

So yes, "$b$ can be anything" in this discussion.